# CommandButton execution while rendering

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Question: How can I prevent the execution of a  while the          website is rendering?

Thats where my Button sits:

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="newComment" height="200" width="500">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid>
            <h:outputText value="#{commentDialog.username}" />
            <h:inputTextarea id="in_text" value="#{commentDialog.text}" />
            <p:message for="in_text" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton validateClient="true" value="Abschicken" ajax="true"
            actionListener="#{popupRequestView.update}" action="PF('newComment').hide();update_popup();" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `action` attribute is intented to execute a backing bean action method on click, not to print some JavaScript code (which of course get executed immediately

You perhaps meant to use `onclick` or `oncomplete` instead. Like as in basic HTML, those `on*` attributes are intented to execute some JavaScript code during the specified HTML event ("click", "complete", etc).

```
oncomplete="PF('newComment').hide();update_popup();"
```

Another cause not visible in the information provided so far is that you forgot to register the `p:` XML namespace. Any `<p:xxx>` tags would then be printed as if it's plain text. Verify if a parent element somewhere in the markup has this:

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Regardless, taking a JSF pause and learning some basic [HTML](http://htmldog.com/guides/html/)/[JavaScript](http://htmldog.com/guides/javascript/) wouldn't be a bad idea. After all, JSF is "just" a HTML/CSS/JS code generator.

Answer (score 0):

you must use primefaces ajaxStatus to prevent click on button while rendering and execute ajax

[ajaxStatus in primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml)